# ColdFusion 11 and Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access, coldfusion, windows-server-2012

I'm running the AWS hourly ColdFusion 11 instance on Windows Server 2012. It's locked down.

I'm trying to access a .MDB file via cfquery (DSN).

I have followed the instructions at http://blogs.coldfusion.com/post.cfm/coldfusion-10-64bit-and-msaccess and http://www.coldfusionmuse.com/index.cfm/2010/12/31/Access.on.64bit.ColdFusion provides almost the same answer.

In addition I have HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/ODBC full permissions to the ColdFusion Windows User.

Per Anit's suggestion I installed the 32-bit AccessDatabaseEngine. I deleted all datasources in both the ODBC tool and CF's admin and re-added them. I also changed the service login from the locked down user to the local service for full rights. I even restarted the whole server.

However I get "[Macromedia][SequeLink JDBC Driver][SequeLink Server]The specified data source is not defined" when running:

```
<cfquery name="CJT" datasource="membersAdministration">
    SELECT *
    FROM MSysObjects
</cfquery>
```

I added the Microsoft Access Datasource in CF Admin giving it a name and database file. The results received as expected was: "Unable to update the NT registry. Variable DRIVERPATH is undefined."

I then ran "C:\Windows\SYSWOW64\odbcad32.exe" and added the System DSN under the same name and path.

I even tried restarting CF.

I see that HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/ODBC and HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Wow6432Node/ODBC have the new entries.

Any ideas what I might be missing?

Here's the stack trace:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Macromedia][SequeLink JDBC Driver][SequeLink Server]The specified data source is not defined.
    at macromedia.sequelink.ssp.Diagnostic.toSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at macromedia.sequelink.ssp.Chain.cnvDiagnostics(Unknown Source)
    at macromedia.sequelink.ssp.Chain.decodeDiagnostic(Unknown Source)
    at macromedia.sequelink.ssp.Chain.decodeBody(Unknown Source)
    at macromedia.sequelink.ssp.Chain.decode(Unknown Source)
    at macromedia.sequelink.ssp.Chain.send(Unknown Source)
    at macromedia.sequelink.ctxt.conn.ConnectionContext.connect(Unknown Source)
    at macromedia.jdbc.sequelink.SequeLinkImplConnection.open(Unknown Source)
    at macromedia.jdbc.slbase.BaseConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at macromedia.jdbc.slbase.BaseConnection.setupImplConnection(Unknown Source)
    at macromedia.jdbc.slbase.BaseConnection.open(Unknown Source)
    at macromedia.jdbc.slbase.BaseDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at macromedia.jdbc.MacromediaDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at coldfusion.server.j2ee.sql.pool.JDBCPool.createPhysicalConnection(JDBCPool.java:614)
    at coldfusion.server.j2ee.sql.pool.ConnectionRunner$RunnableConnection.run(ConnectionRunner.java:67)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: You need to install Microsoft Access 2013 Runtime https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39358

Comment: Why are you using Access? Access is not really designed to be used this way. You would be better off using MySQL, PostgreSQL or SQL Server Express.

Comment: @ScottStroz this is a client requirement for something they acquired. We are fully aware of the consequences.

Comment: @AnitKumar, thank's I'll give that a try. The blog states that was only for .accdb files.

Comment: @AnitKumar, I installed the 32-bit AccessDatabaseEngine. I deleted all datasources in both the ODBC tool and CF's admin and re-added them. I even restarted the whole server. Same result.

Comment: I have not used CF11 (or Access in a long time), so this may be a silly question but ... do you get the same result if you use the MS Access Unicode driver instead? Obviously not the same driver, but I remember having better luck with it than with ODBC last time I played around with it.

Comment: @ChrisTierney, install the 64-bit AccessDatabaseEngine in passive mode as well.

Comment: @Leigh I'll have to track down the Unicode driver. I don't remember seeing it in the lists.

Comment: @AnitKumar I'll give that a go with the 64-bit.

Comment: I actually can not install both at the same time. Error: We can't install the 32-bit version of Office because we found the following 64-bit programs on your PC: Microsoft Access Runtime 2013 and Microsoft Office 32-bit Components 2013. This is the same if I uninstall 64-bit, install 32-bit and install 64-bit. Running: "AccessRuntime_x86_en-us.exe /passive"

Comment: @Leigh I don't have the option for the Unicode drive in CF. Looks like the hack is something I really can't do since I'm using the hourly AMI on Amazon EC2.

Comment: @ChrisTierney, Just as a tweak, can you run C:\Windows\system32\odbcad32.exe" and add the System DSN under the same name and path?

Comment: @AnitKumar that sounds exactly like the step I took for #6 in the blog. Not sure how that's any different?

Comment: Chris, did you notice the difference in the path to odbc in my previous comment. It's not from syswow64. Please try the suggestion in my previous comment. I am already on vacation till next week. So, unfortunately, can't continue to help, but can reconnect, once back.

Comment: @AnitKumar I didn't notice the path change. I'll give that a shot thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post. But I needed to connect some older databases.
ColdFusion 2016 on a Windows 2016 Server. It would not connect to an Access Database.

So I updated everything, Server updated, ColdFusion updates.

I then installed MS Office 2016 (Access) and then updated everything again.

That worked.